# How to extract the name of an HTML item using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extract the name value (which by the way happens to be randomly generated in this case) and be able to use this value as a javascript variable.

The HTML would look something like this:

```
<map name="20934948">
```

I want to get this `20934948` value and use that as a variable.

Example:

```
var myCustomVariableName = extracted javascript
```

So then in this case, `myCustomVariableName` would be `20934948`.

Comment: `extracted javascript` - clearly that won't work ... but `document.querySelector('map').name` will get you the name of the **first** `map` in the document

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed! My guess was `document.querySelector('map name').value;` but I thought that wasn't right so I asked.

Comment: @sdsdc I was typing up an answer to your other question, but you deleted it too soon. It's a slightly tricky problem which is why I couldn't answer it sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain javascript:

```
var myCustomVariableName = document.querySelector('map').name;
console.log(myCustomVariableName);
```

Using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  var jQueryReturn = $('map').attr('name');
  console.log(jQueryReturn);
});
```

```js
var myCustomVariableName = document.querySelector('map').name;
console.log('plain JS : ' + myCustomVariableName);

$(function(){
  var jQueryReturn = $('map').attr('name');
  console.log('jQuery : ' + jQueryReturn);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<map name="20934948">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get the map element
var m = document.getElementsByTagName('map')[0];

// Get the name of the map element
console.log(m.name);
```

Comment: interesting. Looks like I could also use this by defining another variable as `m.name`, like, `var myCustomVar = m.name` after using your first line. Would upvote also if I had 15 points.

Comment: var myCustomVar  = document.getElementsByTagName('map')[0].name; // But do not use this when you need the element for other things. Dont query the DOM with (document.getElementsBy... or document.querySelector...)  for the same element multiple times.